# C# array of numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers

so I have this txt file, which contains a set of various numbers.
How to make the program read that file and show:

- How many numbers are in the file
- what is its sum / mat product
- Minimum/Maximum and average values

so far I've got this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace laboratorinis7
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string skaiciai = "skaiciai.txt";
        string rodymas = File.ReadAllText(skaiciai);
        Console.WriteLine(rodymas);
        Console.ReadLine();
        string[] sa1 = rodymas.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());

        string[] sa2 = new string[0];
        int y = 0;
        foreach (string s in sa1)
        {
            if (s == string.Empty) continue;
            string[] t = s.Split(' ');
            for (int x = 0; x < t.Length; ++x)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref sa2, sa2.Length + 1);
                sa2[y++] = t[x];
            }
        }

        foreach (string S in sa2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(S);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

It displays txt file contents however, no array.

Comment: why do you use `sa2 = new string[0];` and then  `Array.Resize`? simply use `List<string>` and then `List.Add`

Comment: can you show us a snippet of what the file contents look like the first line is all you will need to show to give us an idea.. also you could read all contents into a string[] using lambda statement very easily..

Comment: Also `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: are numbers integer or decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complex. use default .Net implementations to make your code readable and understandable.

```
string skaiciai = "skaiciai.txt";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(skaiciai); // use this to read all text line by line into array of string

List<int> numberList = new List<int>(); // use list instead of array when length is unknown

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{ 
    //if (s == string.Empty) continue; // No need to check for that. Split method returns empty array so you will never go inside inner loop.

    string[] line = lines[i].Split(' ');

    for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
    {
        string number = line[j];
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(number, out n)) // try to parse string into integer. returns true if succeed.
        {
            numberList.Add(n); // add converted number into list
        }
    }
}

// Other way using one line linq to store numbers into list.
//List<int> numberList = lines.SelectMany(x => x.Split(' ')).Select(int.Parse).ToList();

int totalNumbers = numberList.Count;
int sum = numberList.Sum();
int product = numberList.Aggregate((a, b) => a*b);
int min = numberList.Min();
int max = numberList.Max();
double average = sum/(double)totalNumbers;
```

Tell me if your text file contains double numbers because then you have to use double type instead of int.

Also try to use suitable names for variables. names like `t` or `t1` instead of `lines` and `line` does not really describe anything and makes your code harder to understand.

If you have large list of numbers you probably have to use `long` type or `double` if they have decimal part.